# object variable or with block variable not set vba

Tags: vba, excel

So i tried out this code to scrape data from the website. It pulls data from sheet1 then navigates and searches for people. Then it gets certain html tag innertext. This is work time to time partly. Sometimes all 5 pages are successfully open but data is missing in sheet2 where i want to assign the search values and sometimes it gives the error above when it is done only navigating just 2 pages.
VBA tells me error is in line:
PhoneNumber(i) = Doc.getElementsByTagName("td")(2).innerText
How can I successfully scrape all the needed information without a bug.

```
Sub PeopleFinders()

Dim i As Integer
Dim ie As Object
Dim firstname(1 To 5), lastname(1 To 5) As Variant
Dim mm(1 To 5), dd(1 To 5), yyyy(1 To 5) As Variant
Dim PhoneNumber(1 To 5) As Variant
Dim Address(1 To 5) As Variant

For i = 1 To 5
    firstname(i) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value
    lastname(i) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Value
    mm(i) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 3).Value
    dd(i) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 4).Value
    yyyy(i) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 5).Value

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate ("http://www.peoplefinders.com/peoplesearch/searchresults?search=People&fn=" & firstname(i) & "&mn=&ln=" & lastname(i) & "&city=&state=&age=&dobmm=" & mm(i) & "&dobdd=" & dd(i) & "&doby=" & yyyy(i))

    Do While ie.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
    Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
    Set Doc = ie.document

    PhoneNumber(i) = Doc.getElementsByTagName("td")(2).innerText
    Address(i) = Doc.getElementsByTagName("td")(1).innerText

    Sheet5.Cells(i, 1).Value = PhoneNumber(i)
    Sheet5.Cells(i, 2).Value = Address(i)

Next

Set ie = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Since you're declaring your arrays as variant, this isn't an issue but just fyi, you need to declare type for all variables. `dim x, y as integer` means only y is type int, x is variant.

Comment: `Doc.getElementsByTagName("td")(2).innerText` will error out if there is not a 2nd element on the page for the tag "td". You should error check for this so your code will run through.